# Visual c++ "for each" portability

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, foreach

I only just recently discovered that Visual C++ 2008 (and perhaps earlier versions as well?) supports `for each` syntax on stl lists et al to facilitate iteration.
For example:

```
list<Object> myList;

for each (Object o in myList)
{
  o.foo();
}
```

I was very happy to discover it, but I'm concerned about portability for the dreaded day when someone decides I need to be able to compile my code in say, gcc or some other compiler. Is this syntax widely supported and can I use it without worrying about portability issues?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For each is not standard C or C++ syntax. If you want to be able to compile this code in gcc or g++, you will need to create an iterator and use a standard for loop.

QuantumPete

[edit]
This seems to be a new feature introduced into MS Visual C++, so this is definitely not portable. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw%28VS.80%29.aspx [/edit]

Answer (score 35):

I wouldn't use that. While it's a tempting feature, the syntax is incompatible with the upcoming C++0x standard, which uses:

```
list<Object> myList;

for (Object o : myList)
{
   o.foo();
}
```

to do the same thing.

Answer (score 21):

There is a very good portable alternative: [Boost.Foreach](http://engineering.meta-comm.com/resources/cs-win32_metacomm/doc/html/foreach.html). Just dump this header into your project and you can write your loops as follows:

```
list<Object> myList;

BOOST_FOREACH(Object o, myList)
    o.foo();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you'd like to use foreach and in the same time you don't want to add additional dependency (such as Boost) - this macro will help you:

```
#define VAR(V,init) __typeof(init) V=(init)
#define FOREACH(I,C) for(VAR(I,(C).begin());I!=(C).end();I++)

std::vector<int> numbers;

FOREACH(I, numbers)
{
    std::cout << *I << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Visual C++ "for each" is not standard C++, meaning you won't be able to compile your code on other compilers such as g++. However, the STL proposes [std::for_each](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/for_each.html), but its syntax is a lot less intuitive. Here is its prototype:

```
template <class InputIterator, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryFunction f);
```

It takes two iterators defining a valid range, and applies the unary function (or functor) f to each object in this range.
You can rewrite your example using std::for_each like this:

```
void foo(Object o)
{
  o.foo();
}
...
list<Object> myList;

std::for_each(myList.begin(), myList.end(), foo);
```

However, if you want to stay close to the classical syntax of the for each construct, and if you're ok about using Boost, you can use [BOOST.FOREACH](http://engineering.meta-comm.com/resources/cs-win32_metacomm/doc/html/foreach.html), which will let you write

```
list<Object> myList;

BOOST_FOREACH(Object o, myList)
{
    o.foo();
}
```

Comment: Note: for each (a in b) seems to be CLR only even in VS 2005/2008 - you cannot use it in native code, only when targeting .NET, making for each even "less portable".

Otherwise I think your answer is excellent.

Comment: Also note that if you're using VS2010, you have lambdas and std::for_each() suddenly becomes easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

The Boost Library has a portable [ForEach imlementation](http://engineering.meta-comm.com/resources/cs-win32_metacomm/doc/html/foreach.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is indeed not portable.

The following works with the C++ 0x standard and Visual C++ 2010 (which doesn't support the new "ranged for" syntax as far as I can tell).

```
#define for_each(_ITER_, _COLL_) for (auto _ITER_ = _COLL_.begin(); \
    _ITER_ != _COLL_.end(); _ITER_++)
```

Now you can write:

```
list<Object> myList;

for_each (o, myList)
{
  o.foo();
}
```

Compare this to the BOOST_FOREACH macro code at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/foreach.hpp which is not only complex it also has a number of dependencies on other boost libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend BOOST_FOREACH. I usually create a macro along the lines of:

```
#define _foreach(x,y) BOOST_FOREACH(x,y)
```

This tends to increase readability. You have to be careful about collisions with other foreach implementations though. For instance, Qt provides a 'foreach' and there's the std::for_each.

I find that the std::for_each doesn't actually save much time since you end up making lots of one-off function objects to supply to the for_each call. It's usually just as fast to make standard for-loop using STL iterators.

Comment: In Boost.Foreach documentation, they explicitly advise against the way you write your define. Write "#define _foreach BOOST_FOREACH" instead.

Comment: I like to keep it as BOOST_FOREACH simply because it reminds that it's a macro expansion and to be careful about what I put inside it.

Answer (score -1):

My vote goes for Luc,

Stick to the standard STL algorithms and you will be better off by far.  STL algorithms can make your life very easy, efficient and safe. Take a look at the off the shelve algorithms like find_if, count, count_if, sort, transform, etc...

Point 5 onwards... 
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html

Boost is cool, but if you are going to use it just for the FOR_EACH macro it is too much cumbersome regarding the development/build environment setup.

use boost when standard c++ / stl cannot solve the problem in an 'easy' way.