# Is "for each" Microsoft specific?

Tags: c++, syntax, foreach, c++11

Visual C++ 2010 accepts:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
for each (auto i in v)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

Is this a C++11 feature or a Microsoft extension? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach#C.2B.2B), the syntax of C++11's for-each loop different:

```
int myint[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (int& i: myint)
{
    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual c++ "for each" portability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197375/visual-c-for-each-portability)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The current standard draft does not include the `for each ( auto i in v )` syntax, only the `for ( auto i : myints )`, so yes, it is just an extension.

Answer (score 4):

In VS2010, for any such doubt, try with the `/Za` flag under `"C/C++->Language"` in the IDE project settings.

As for your query, yes, this is not standard C++ syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Besides of the for loops version presented above a c++0x standard conformal version would also be:

```
std::for_each (v.begin(), v.end(), [] (int)->void { 
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
});
```

The construct you have presented, is also standard conformal, but it conforms to different standard: The ECMA C++/CLI specification.

Comment: If it is as he said, that it compiles to native code, wouldn't it be C++ instead of C++/Cli? Or is he wrong? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Technically, "C++0x standard" is an oxymoron. It's not a standard yet. (And when it becomes one, it'll no longer be called C++0x) ;)

Comment: @jalf Well, since we do not have a better name for it yet, I think that one is the best available... @Johannes No, this always compiles to IL, or to that mysterious mixture of IL and native code. This syntax may only work, if you compile with CLR support (/clr option).

Comment: I have to correct my comment from above. With vc9 and vc10 this syntax compiles in native code too. This should not be, the /clr option should be required for that.

Comment: I know, just being pedantic. ;) (although I'd say "C++0x conformant", without the "standard". Or just "a C++0x version"

Answer (score 3):

I'd also like to note a caveat of Microsoft's "for each" loop; using STL containers such as std::vector, you cannot pass variables by reference, only by value and const reference. For example:

```
int myarr [] = {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15};
std::vector<int> mvt (myarr, myarr+6);

for each (int & x in mvt) //will not compile for reasons unbeknownst to those outside MS
   x+= 4;
```

If your compiler supports C++0x range-based for I'd use that instead.  If not, I would use BOOST_FOREACH or std::for_each with a function object or lambda as these are portable. Whatever you do, stay clear from Microsoft's "for each".

Comment: using `for each (const int & x in mvt)` works and you can use `const_cast` to make the item editable