# Dijkstra's Algorithm issue [repost]

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I realized I can't post answers to my own questions because of my low rep or whatever so i deleted my old question and am reasking it. i changed some things and still can't get what i'm looking for.

Here is most of the code
I left out some of the simpler implementations such as parts of the pathFinder class because I know for sure they work, which is why you'll see playerVertex and time just randomly there. 
In the example they used a decreaseKey function, I'm not sure if THAT'S what I'm missing? I'm a beginner here, so constructive criticism is welcome. (hopefully as polite as possible) lol. My problem is printing the path, I get a looop of the same two values over and over again.

```
class Heap 
{
public: Heap();
    ~Heap();
    void insert(double element);
    double  deletemin();
    void print();
    int size(){return heap.size();}


private:
 int currentIndex;
 int left(int parent);
 int right(int parent);
 int parent(int child);
 void heapifyup(int index);
 void heapifydown(int index);
private:
 vector<double> heap;
};

Heap::Heap()
{
 currentIndex = 0;
}
Heap::~Heap()
{}

void Heap::insert(double element)
{
heap.push_back(element);
currentIndex++;
heapifyup(heap.size() - 1);
}

double Heap::deletemin()
{
double min = heap.front();
heap[0] = heap.at(heap.size()-1);
heap.pop_back();
heapifydown(0);
currentIndex--;
return min;
}
void Heap::print()
{
vector<double>::iterator pos = heap.begin();
cout << "Heap = ";
while ( pos != heap.end() ) 
{
    cout << *pos;
    ++pos;
    cout << endl;
 }
}
void Heap::heapifyup(int index)
{


while((index>0) && (parent(index) >=0) && (heap[parent(index)] > heap[index]))
{
 double tmp = heap[parent(index)];
 heap[parent(index)] = heap[index];
 heap[index] = tmp;
 index = parent(index);


}
}

void Heap::heapifydown(int index)
{



int child = left(index);

if((child > 0) && (right(index) > 0) && (heap[child]>heap[right(index)]))
{
 child = right(index);

}
if(child > 0)
{
double tmp = heap[index];
heap[index] = heap[child];
heap[child] = tmp;
heapifydown(child);
}
}

int Heap::left(int parent)
{
int i = ( parent <<1) + 1; 
return(i<heap.size()) ? i : - 1;
}

int Heap::right(int parent)
{
int i = ( parent <<1) + 2; 
return(i<heap.size()) ? i : - 1;
}

int Heap::parent(int child)
{
if(child != 0)
{
 int i = (child - 1) >>1;
 return i;
}
return -1;
}



class pathFinder : public weightedGraph
{

private:

vertex* playerVertex;
double time;


public:
string source;
pathFinder()
{
    playerVertex = NULL;
    time = 0;

}


  void Dijkstra(int s,int t)
{
    vertex *verts = findVertex(grid[s][t]);
    Heap H;
    for each(vertex *v in vertexList)
    {

        if(v->data == verts->data)
        {
            verts->distance = 0;
            verts->pred = NULL;
        }
        v->distance = INFINITY;
        v->pred = NULL;
        H.insert(v->data);
    }
    while(H.size() != 0)
    {

        vertex *x = findVertex(H.deletemin());

        for each(edge *v in x->adjacencyList)
        {

            if(v->end->visited != true)
            {    
            relax(x,v->end);
            v->end->visited = true;
            }
            else
                break;

        }

    }
}








void relax(vertex *a, vertex *b)
{

    if(a->distance + weightFrom(a,b) > b->distance)
        {
            b->distance = a->distance + weightFrom(a,b);
            b->pred = a;
        }


}


void printPath(double dest,double dest1)
{
    vertex *verta = findVertex(dest);
    while(verta->pred->data != dest1)
    {
    cout<<verta->data<<endl;
    verta = verta->pred;
    }
}
```

and i'm not sure about the print path being that. i just used the print path from the BFS algorithm i've implemented before.

Comment: just need anything please!

Comment: `for each` is not standard c++, is there a macro `each` defined somewhere?

Comment: @DavidBrown I don't think so. It must be a part of my Visual Studio, a compiler extension or something.

Comment: @DavidBrown The OP is right, it's [specific to the MSVC compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197375/visual-c-for-each-portability). I recommend using [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/foreach.html) instead for better portability, or if you are using C++11 (and only need your code to be portable to other C++11 compilers), then [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/c11-how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap).

Comment: I don't think you're ensuring the heap condition is being maintained. After you relax the nodes, you need to ensure the heap is re-ordered to respect the new costs. Not doing that probably means that you are generating loops in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Where in your `printPath` function are you looking for the end of the list?

You keep going `verta = verta->pred` until the data is not equal to some value.

By the way, don't compare doubles for equality, as it ain't going to happen.  See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

What happens when you single step with your debugger?
(Try drawing the links and how you traverse them.)

Comment: yea like i said i used the printPath function from BFS so i'm not sure if it's right lol. i'm trying to do Dijkstra's on let's say [0][0] in a grid. then i do print path from [3][3] going from pred to pred until it reaches [0][0]. this is the BFS print out. i'm not sure if that's how you print out in Dijkstra's.