# Is for each statement legal in C++11

Tags: c++11, for-loop, visual-studio-2013, range

In Visual Studio 2013, below statement is legal. I couldn't find it on cppreference.com. Is this in C++11 standard? Can someone link a reference?

```
vector<string> items = { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" };
for each (string item in items)  
{
    cout << item << endl;
}
```

I only know this one is legal in C++11.

```
for (auto& item: items) {}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual c++ "for each" portability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197375/visual-c-for-each-portability)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx):

> Iterates through an array or collection. This non-standard keyword is available in both C++/CLI and native C++ projects. However, its use is not recommended. Consider using a standard Range-based for Statement (C++) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Both g++-4.10 and clang-3.4 support (with -std=c++1z) a simplified range for statement:

```
for (item: items) {}
```

this is equivalent to:

```
for (auto&& item: items) {}
```

where the rvalue reference will collapse to `const auto&` for a const items range.
The design of this feature actually references the C++/CLI for each statement as implementation experience.

Since the guy who designed [this feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3994.htm) for std C++ works for Microsoft I strongly suspect Visual Studio either might or very soon will have this feature.

From the paper:

> Implementation experience actually exists to guide this decision. 
>   Visual C++ provides the non-Standard syntax "for each (Elem elem in
>   range)".  In addition to being more verbose and less flexible than
>   C++11's range-for syntax (which permits ADL customization), the
>   implementation of "for each" adds constness for poorly understood
>   reasons, so "for each (Elem& elem in range)" cannot be used to modify
>   elements in-place.  This limitation has repeatedly confused users, as
>   encountered on Microsoft's internal mailing lists.

Comment: I think you meant `-std=c++0x`, but he should be using `-std=c++11` by now anyway. Also, GCC and Clang support *range-based for loops* for quite a while now (with the `-std=c++0x` flag). Visual Studio has added support for them since the 2012 version.

Comment: @MihaiTodor I know about -std=c++11 - it will get you the range loop but you still have to supply auto&& or something. Most compilers have -std=c++14 (-std=c++1y maybe) and recently even -std=c++1z for the planned C++17.  I'm saying that many compilers are starting to implement C++17 slated things - one of which is the terse range for loop inspired in part by for each.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm sorry. Please ignore my comment. I didn't realize that there are plans to simplify the range-based for loops even more, so I completely misread your answer...